# Fluctuating op-amp output

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, analog, piezo

I've presented this schematic before in bits and broken pieces but I finished it, but I'm still not getting the results I want and expect.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foC4FQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To elaborate, I have connected all grounds together.

BAT1 providing 5.09V is a 9V battery connected to an LM317 regulator and provides a constant voltage.

BAT2 is a 9V battery and the voltage divider gives a constant 2.92V in order to bias my signal from the piezo to read the negative voltages. When attached on its own I get a nice flat bias. 
[image]

I currently have 2 errors firstly,

The piezo sensor portion was adapted from here [Here](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IsPRd-5PoBQ/TazKONiVsSI/AAAAAAAABDI/3oe3bCDTYRI/s1600/Papydoo%2B-%2BOpAmp.gif) The resistors provide a gain of 11 and my multimeter shows that the op-amp (OA4) it is amplifying, however, when I get readings through on the Rpi it fluctuates around 0.5-0.7V. (The spikes at the end are me tapping the piezo to show that it does react to stimulus)

[image]

And secondly, when the bias and the piezo are both fed into the ADC it doesn't fluctuate around 2.92V it drops to ~0.2V and fluctuates, again the spikes are me.

[image]
Finally, this last graph shows the output if the op-amp is avoided by the piezo and just goes through 1Mohm resistor to ground.

[image]
Can anyone explain why the voltages are fluctuating like this and why when both the inputs are connected to the MCP3001 ADC I don't get the expected results?
Thank you.

EDIT:
The two ways I interpret the two responses.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjoYnj.png)</sup>

Comment: This question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191472/negative-voltage-adc-and-op-amp has a legit answer so maybe you can either say why you think it isn't or formally accept it.

Comment: Currently BAT2 and its circuit are shown as doing nothing except waste power. No ground connection here???

Comment: I have re-read that question and it does seem to be relevant. However, I'm not sure how you mean to wire it up. I have added an edit, can you please clarify? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. TL081s don't run from a 5v supply - read the data sheet (10V minimum recommended)
2. You can't superimpose a bias on the output of an op-amp in order to centralize it to suit the ADC - feed it onto where the piezo is via a high value resistor to get ~2.5volts on the op-amp output
3. Choose an op-amp with rail-to-rail capability.
4. The feedback network of 100 ohms and 10 ohms is too low - try 1k and 100 ohms
5. I have absolutely no idea whay you have a diode and a capacitor on the op-amp output.

That's enough I believe for now.

Comment: Sorry, the op-amp and resistor values were labelled incorrectly, they've been adjusted. Can you explain how to feed the bias into the op-amp?

Comment: Look thru answers given previously - I explain it there and while you are at it accept answers that you now belive to be correct. SE.EE isn't a charity - there is give and take on both sides.

Comment: So maybe the brave downvoter can explain his or her action?