# circuit to measure positive & negative voltage + Vref resolution

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, adc, voltage-measurement, instrumentation-amplifier

i would like to make a "voltmeter" to read from +2V to -2V and connect it to an Arduino ADC ( 0V to 5V ).
I found different configurations for do this job:

1. From this [site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/252431/measure-both-positive-and-negative-voltages-using-adc): 
   [image]
2. Bipolar to unipolar [converter](https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/design-a-bipolar-to-unipolar-converter/), a summing amp:
   [image]
3. Instrumental amp, base on this schematic ( ECG ):
   [image]

The last approach use:
 - instrumental amp
 - full-wave rectifier
 - low pass filter
 - inverting opamp + gain

The signal i need to read it's "stable", the ECG circuit i suppose it's too complex for this job. But i'm interested to compare the instrumental amp Vs opamp.

What is the best configuration for my porspose?

For the Vref, I have this question:

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xI_qU2auVx8) & this [article](http://tronixstuff.com/2013/12/12/arduino-tutorials-chapter-22-aref-pin/) are show how it works.
In the article he say, for example:
Vref at 5v -> 0-5 V has 4.9 mV resolution
Vref at 3.3v -> 0-3.3 has 3.2mV resolution
But in the video does not say that, he used Vref at 1.1v and apparently does not have any problem.... probably the solution is here in the [code](https://github.com/SensorsIot/ADC_Test/blob/master/ADC_Test.ino#L63).

Answer (score 2):

This does not directly answer your question but may give you an idea for a different solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjL08P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The simplest offset adjust.*

If you can live with reduced resolution on the ADC the circuit of Figure 1 may be acceptable.

```
Vin       Vout
-2 V      +1.5 V
 0 V      +2.5 V
+2 V      +3.5 V
```

It reduces the 5 V span to only 2 V with the resistor arrangement shown.

I think the best span you can get with this arrangement will be by reducing R1 to 2k. With this ratio the ADC starts at 0 V.

```
Vin       Vout
-2 V       0 V
 0 V      +1.428 V
+2 V      +2.857 V
```

You can scale the resistors to suit. The ratio is what is important.

Comment: Nice solution @Transistor, but i had done some changes in the circuit:   

I must use an external [ADC](https://goo.gl/7hg3JY) and a single Lipo battery.   
This is the circuit i draw:   
https://ibb.co/cv9Ony

You can simulate here:    
http://tinyurl.com/y8ct5e87    
Is it a good solution?

Comment: Only to clarify... This humble 2-resistor network is the possibly simplest voltage summer with weighted inputs. It can be easily analysed by the superposition principle: Vadc = Vcc.R1/(R1 + R2) + Vin.R2/(R1 + R2) = (Vcc + Vin)/2. It can be thought as of a voltage divider driven from both ends. It is usually used to convert the bipolar voltage from -5 to +5 V into positive voltage from 0 to +5 V.