# Negative and positive voltage sensor Arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage, circuit-design

I want build a negative and positive voltage sensor with an Arduino. I found this article:
[Read Positive and Negative Voltage in Arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108320/read-positive-and-negative-voltage-in-arduino).

There is the circuit I need, but with some modifications. I want to measure cell voltage so I want only voltages around -1.5 V to 1.5 V. So in my case I will use 3.3 V from the Arduino as power supply. I have few questions:

1. What should be the new values of the resistors (please specify one by one) (blue ones)
2. Should the measurement probes be in the positions marked in purple?
3. Did I mark correctly how I will connect the pins (green text)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If posible pls also explain how did you count new resistor values. Im only statistician :D non electronic guy :)

Answer (score 1):

This voltage divider will give you the most dynamic range without an amplifier. R1 is chosen to provide a voltage drop of 1.5V at 500uA, so for -1.5V the ADC will see zero. R2 is chosen to drop 3.3V at 500uA. So the ADC input will be 0, 1.06, and 2.12 volts. You can make the values of R1 and R2 equal if you want to have the ADC centered at 1.65V (1/2 Vdd) for 0V input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHLUnL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: ADC Input Scaler +/-1.5V to 3.3V]

Comment: But i need to measure values bettwen -1.5v : 1.5v and as i understand your propousal can measure only 3 values. In my cause every 1mV is important

Comment: No, those are just the limits of measurement. For +1.5V, the ADC will read 639 counts out of the maximum of 1024. So that is 4.7 mV/count. If you can set the reference to 2.12V you could get 2.9 mV/count.

Comment: Please also explain me what is( csv v1 pwl), what is input and what is output (probes)?

Comment: And also can you tell me if I make 5v it will make my measurements more detailed?

Comment: Depends on what you really need. Do you have actual specifications? I think I have adequately answered your original question. Have the parameters changed now?

Comment: No. I just want to know where should is put my probes.

Comment: And what is CSV?

Comment: And where is the place for A1 (analog pin)?

Comment: Comma Separated Values, pairs of time and voltage, used for the time domain simulation. You should learn how to use CircuitLab. The ADC input would be on the node shown as "output".

Comment: Do i understan it fine? In red points should be measuerment electrodes. And rest also i understand fine like PIN 3.3, PIN GND, PIN A1? [my schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh9od.png)

Comment: Yes. Just try it.